# no burner support

Tags: windows-vista, burning, compact-disc, optical-drive, ahci

most freeware cd/dvd burning software (cdxpburner,burnaware,etc) report either no support or do not recognize my laptop dvd writer. Just purchased a new laptop with this problem. It is a lenovo G530 laptop with vista home premium os with Optiarc dvd rw ad-7580s ata device. Ashampoo suite does recognize the burner but i prefer the more compact freeware burning software and am looking for a workaround.
Brian 
PS comments on the cdxpburner forum and the burnaware support point to the mode AHCI as at the root of the problem but with no straight forward solution. My technical knowledge is limited and would appreciate help. Did not experience the same problem with XP Professional on a Fujitsi Siemens V2045 laptop

Answer (score 3):

Try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/). You didn't mention it in your post as not working. I've been using it for about a year and I've had no problems with it.

Comment: ImgBurn is the best writer for Windows ever, and it's totally free. Amongst the "musthave" ones. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent [query for Vista at this techsupportforum](http://www.techsupportforum.com/hardware-support/removable-media-drives/341170-optiarc-dvd-rw-ad7580s-burner-inoperable.html).
It refers this [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929461).

There is also a CDFreaks interaction in the **Support** tag at the
[NEC 8X Slim DVD Multi Writer](http://www.cdfreaks.com/hardware/product/69090-NEC-8X-Slim-DVD-Multi-Writer.html) page.

If nothing else works, you could post your problem there.

---

Old: I take it you have already used this and the question just has a typo.
Here is one more tool for you to try out: [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/help/).

It might help if you get the `Brian PS` comments links here.

Comment: He mentions that it doesn't work in the first line

Comment: I add another quote: "Ashampoo suite does recognize the burner but i prefer the more compact freeware burning software and am looking for a workaround."

Comment: And, i thought, CDXPBurner is different from CDBurnerXP --- they do have a shortage of good application names (nothing like that seems to hit the Unix world, where people get quite imaginative with names)